# Interpreting probability conditions from question

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function

I've encountered this question:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlE1w.jpg]

And got the answer here:

[image]

However, what I don't quite understand is how are the two conditions derived from the question in the first place.

Comment: For short text scans like this it would probably be better just to use the "quotation" mode in the question editor. Please consider editing to do this. In the interim, I've embedded the images. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @cardinal. Is there a guide/help page on how I can do so?

Comment: Welcome to the site, user. You can find info on @cardinal's suggestion in [CV's markdown help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions are not derived from that question. The conditions are imposed on any function which can be considered as a probability distribution.